# Accessing the current request in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-request

In other MVC frameworks, accessing to the current request object is as simple as `$this->request`. However in the Laravel, I generally see that `Request $request` is generally injected to each action (`public function edit($id, Request $request)`). It seems like a boilerplate. Is there any better way to access the request? (I now that I can use inheritance to use `$this->request`, I am looking for the Laravel way to do that.)

## update:

I found out using `app('request')` I can access to the current request. However, I am not sure of its potential pros and cons.

Comment: `public function edit($id, Request $request)` isn't really "boilerplate", it's dependency injection -- that's Laravel's way of doing things most places. You can also use Facades if you prefer: `Request::current()`, or save the request to `$this->request` in your constructor.

Comment: @Ben `Request::current()` is undefined. ` Request $request` is not in the methods created by artisan. `request` object is almost always need in controller's method and sending it repetitively  as a parameter is definitely a boilerplate.

Answer (score 9):

In Laravel 5, you can use the `request()` helper:

```
// to get the current request object
$request = request();

// or to just get a value from the request
$value = request("field", "default");
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-request